# desktop automation with robotgo , build fails on windows 10

Tags: go, zlib

On running this Command go get github.com/go-vgo/robotgo
 I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:174:13: undefined: windows.EnumProcesses
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:212:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:216:12: undefined: windows.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:281:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:384:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:448:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:494:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:798:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:813:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:847:32: undefined: windows.PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\shirou\gopsutil\process\process_windows.go:847:32: too many errors
```

Go version is 1.9

once I updated sys/windows I started getting this exception:

```
D:\golang\prj4\src>go build main.go
# github.com/go-vgo/robotgo
In file included from ./bitmap/../base/str_io_c.h:2,
                 from ./bitmap/goBitmap.h:17,
                 from C:\Users\<removed>\go\src\github.com\go-vgo\robotgo\robotgo.go:45:
./bitmap/../base/zlib_util_c.h:2:10: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <zlib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Are you sure Go 1.9 is supported? That version is ancient. You should upgrade if possible, ideally to 1.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a closed [issue #743](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/743) (and [#835](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/835)) for this in [shirou/gopsutil](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil) Github repo.

[Citation with the fixture](https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil/issues/743#issuecomment-519241791):

> I don't think it's related to Go version, but to
>   `golang.org/x/sys/windows` version, can you try updating it with `go get -u golang.org/x/sys/windows`?

Comment: updating the sys/windows removed all those error , but now it is giving me new error, I have updated my question with this new error, it is about zlib, on robotgo github , they mentioned to download and put it manually in tdm bin directory but I am not able to find this library